# how can i solve pwa-studio yarn build callback error?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, magento2, yarn-v2, pwa-studio

when i run command yarn build in my projrct

i fetch error like this

/pwa-studio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:106
throw new Error("callback(): The callback was already called.

when i run command yarn build in my projrct

i fetch error like this

/pwa-studio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:106
throw new Error("callback(): The callback was already called.

i am also try to remove node_module folder but still i get this error

any suggestions?

Comment: Have you resolve this issue ?